# Submitting form with W A S D without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'making 2D game which have simple walking code that sets position with form but with reloading page.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;

  function KeyCheck(e)
    {
       var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

        switch(KeyID)
        {
            case 87:
                function up() 
                {
                document.navi.keydir.value = "up";
                document.navi.submit();
                }
                var uptime;
                uptime = setTimeout(up, 1000);
                break;
            case 65:
                function left() 
                {
                document.navi.keydir.value = "left";
                document.navi.submit();
                }
                var lefttime;
                lefttime = setTimeout(left, 1000);          
                break;
            case 68:
                function right() 
                {
                document.navi.keydir.value = "right";
                document.navi.submit();

                var righttime;
                righttime = setTimeout(right, 1000);
                break;
            case 83:
                function down() 
                {
                document.navi.keydir.value = "down";
                document.navi.submit();
                }
                var downtime;
                downtime = setTimeout(down, 1000);
                break;
        }
    } 
</script>


<form id="navi" name="navi" class="navi" action="move.php" method="post">
<input name="keydir" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
```

I need script that will post this form to MYSQL using this keys without reloading page.

EDIT: I made this form work with 
$("#navi").ajaxSubmit({url: 'move.php', type: 'post'})

But if someone can tell me is it good for page overload???

Comment: You need a second page to POST the data to using ajax, just as using the jquery library.  The other page will accept the POST data, sanatize it and insert your database record. Google "jquery form ajax post"

Comment: You can see how it work on http://cebulowapatola.pe.hu login:test password:test

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to move around.  So you need a take a two prong approach for user experience.  First, let the user move around the map with out a post using AJAX and just move the user using JS.  If teh AJAX call fails, alert the user and return them to the last known valid position.

Answer (score 0):

First, just move the user.  Secrond, turn document.navi.submit() into a async ajax call that if it fails, move the user back to the last known good position.

Comment: To moving user i want to use javascript script which reloads my player in some time like other players

Comment: And for game window i should use div or canvas?

Comment: Right, I am saying to use two JS calls.  One to move the user, the second to make the ajax call i.e.  moveUser() if(ajax.failure() || ajax.result.dbnotsaved)) moveUserBack()

Comment: Using the HTML5 canvas may be easier, but what you are doing will work too.

Comment: Can you tell me a good free hosting without ads?Because this hosting is crap.